# read in .txt file than split it into 3 columns

Tags: r

(Edited)Pretty new at this R stuff but I find it very interesting. Trying to follow  this tutorial. OK so what I am trying to do is some text manipulation like strip white space, convert case, filter stop words but first I want to read it into a dataframe that contains 3 columns. 
I am trying to read in the data in this zip file=

http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~tiago/smsspamcollection/smsspamcollection.zip

which is a .txt file of ham and spam messages. I want to split it up into three columns "ID", "Text" , "Class" . "ID" being the unique identifier of the String, "Text" is the actual message, and "Class" is the "ham" or "spam" classifiers of the messages.

What I have so far is ...

```
dat = readLines("SMSSpamCollection.txt")
dat = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(dat, split="\t")), 
                                                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(dat) = c("ID", "Class" , "Text")
```

This does read it into the dataframe but it does not recognise the index as the "ID" column ,Any help?

Comment: There's a tab between the columns (it's really a .tsv), so split on `"\t"`. Simpler: `df <- read.table('SMSSpamCollection.txt', sep = '\t', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = '', col.names = c('class', 'text'))`

Comment: That worked !  But it says that the index I need as the "ID" is not a column.  It tells me it has more column names than columns.

Comment: If you look at the file, there are only two columns of data. Are you referring to the rownames? You can add them as a column after the fact, if you like.

Comment: Awesome, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This file does not contain identifiers. It has only two variables, 'Class' and 'Text'. The names would be 'Class' and 'Text'.

Comment: dat$ID = c(1:nrow(dat))

Comment: Thank you so much, I didnt realise I had to keep rownames in order to use them.